# MySQL records from second query not showing if first query returns (semi-)empty in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a tool for the company I work for to check the occupancy rate of our apartments. The aim is to see the current tenant, when his contract started and when it will end, and if there already is a new tenant (and the date the new tenant will start renting).

For this, I'm pulling data from our 'apartments' database that left joins our 'tenants' database. I'm running the following query first (in PHP) to list all of the tenants that are currently occupying an apartment, by checkin if the start date is in the past and the end date is in the future. Because I want to list every apartment (even if they're not occupied), I'm also selecting the apartments where 'startdate_true' is NULL:

```
$tenantquery = "
SELECT * 
  FROM apartments 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tenants 
    ON apartments.apartmentno = tenants.currentlyrenting 
 WHERE startdate_true IS NULL 
    OR startdate_true < CURDATE() 
   AND enddate_true > CURDATE() 
ORDER BY apartments.apartmentid ASC
";
```

This returns (as expected) all of the apartments and whether they are occupied or not. I'm outputting this in an HTML table, with help of a PHP while-loop.

Next, I want to see if there is already a new tenant that will occupy the apartment after the current tenant. To do this, I'm running the following query **inside** of the while-loop:

```
$nextquery = "
SELECT * 
  FROM apartments 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tenants 
    ON apartments.apartmentno = tenants.currentlyrenting 
 WHERE apartments.apartmentno = '" . $row['apartmentno'] . "' 
   AND startdate_true > CURDATE()
";
```

Here, I'm selecting the apartment that is currently in the while-loop and fetch the tenant from the database that has a starting date in the future. This query outputs correctly, but only if the apartment is already occupied. For example:

```
Apartment: **1A**
Status: **Occupied**
Tenant: **John Doe**
End date: **2020-06-30**
Next tenant: **Jane Doe**
Startdate next tenant: **2020-07-01**
```

However, every apartment that is currently not occupied, but will be in the future, doesn't list the 'future tenant', it just returns nothing. For example:

```
Apartment: **1B**
Status: **Not occupied**
Tenant: **none**
End date: **none**
Next tenant: **none**
Startdate next tenant: **none**
```

When running the second query (to check the future tenants) in my PHPMyAdmin, it returns my wanted results, but in PHP it doesn't. I find it very strange that it only outputs future tenants if the said apartment is already occupied.

Does someone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use line breaks. This is hardly readable.

Comment: @GhostGambler my apologies! should be good now.

Comment: If you had some parentheses, where would you put them?

Comment: And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You might also like to move    `AND startdate_true > CURDATE()` up one line

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for your replies, I really don't know if -or where- I should put parentheses. I've moved that one piece of the query up one line, but that didn't make a difference, I think. Any other ideas, or do you need some further explanation?

Comment: Yes, see the linked answer above

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't necessarily solve your problem, here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant  
  FROM apartments a
  LEFT 
  JOIN tenants t
    ON t.currentlyrenting = a.apartmentno 
   AND ( t.startdate_true IS NULL 
      OR ( t.startdate_true < CURDATE() AND t.enddate_true > CURDATE() )
       )
 ORDER 
    BY a.apartmentid ASC
```